# Excel: Highlight rows where duplicate values exist in multiple columns including blanks

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have the following formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$84164,$B21,$E$2:$E$84164,$E21)>1,"Yes","No")
```

It works fine except for when column E is blank. It doesn't show it as a duplicate i.e. thinks it is unique.

So let's say I have the following

```
A    B    C    D    E
---------------------
A   |2   |B   |C   |
X   |2   |Y   |Z   |
```

It won't pick these two rows as duplicates despite them being duplicates. If both fields have a value, it's fine, it's just if either one has a blank

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you should surround your `=Counif()` in ‘iferror()’, like this

`=IF(iferror(COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$84164,$B21,$E$2:$E$84164,$E21), 0.5)>1,"Yes","No")`

I just threw a random condition case, as an example.

`Iferror` handles the error in any functions, sometimes is really useful when you do expect an error in some function

Comment: I'll try this but not sure why this would work - there's no error, it's just that it sees it as a unique row rather than a duplicate - no error is being thrown for me to capture